# How to make async call in the client Interceptor method AsyncUnaryCall

Tags: c#, grpc

I try to implement some caching functionality for the grpc client call.
There is a custom interceptor which overrides the method AsyncUnaryCall for handling client calls. But it doesn't compile as AsyncUnaryCall returns its own type instead of async Task so it doesn't allow it to make awaitable calls.

```
    internal class MyCacheInterceptor : Interceptor
    {
        private readonly IMyCacheService _cacheService;

        public MyCacheInterceptor(IMyCacheService cacheService)
        {
            _cacheService = cacheService;
        }

        public override AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse> AsyncUnaryCall<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context,
            AsyncUnaryCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
        {

            var key = GetCacheKey(request, context);
            var cacheValue = await _cacheService.GetCacheAsync<TResponse>(key);
            if (cacheValue != null)
            {
                var test = new AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse>(
                    Task.FromResult(cacheValue),
                    null!,
                    null!,
                    null!,
                    null!);
            }
            else
            {
                return base.AsyncUnaryCall(request, context, continuation);
            }
        }
    }
```

I found a similar question here https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/21489 and [ASPNET CORE GRPC async interceptor method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61654884/aspnet-core-grpc-async-interceptor-method)

They use

```
var ctn = continuation(request, context);
```

but calling the continuation delegate actually starts grpc request to the server.

So are there some workarounds on how can I achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2):

OK; this is untested - I cannot emphasize quite how untested this is! but:

```cs
public override AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse> AsyncUnaryCall<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context,
          AsyncUnaryCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation) where TRequest : class where TResponse : class
    {
        var obj = new MyStateObj<TRequest, TResponse>(_cacheService, request, context, continuation);
        return new AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse>(obj.Response,
            static s => ((MyStateObj<TRequest, TResponse>)s).Headers,
            static s => ((MyStateObj<TRequest, TResponse>)s).Status,
            static s => ((MyStateObj<TRequest, TResponse>)s).Trailers,
            static s => ((MyStateObj<TRequest, TResponse>)s).Dispose(),
            obj);
    }

    class MyStateObj<TRequest, TResponse>
        where TRequest : class
        where TResponse: class
    {
        private readonly TaskCompletionSource<TResponse> response = new();
        private readonly TaskCompletionSource<Metadata> headers = new();
        private AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse>? call;
        public Status Status { get; private set; }
        public Metadata Trailers { get; private set; } = Metadata.Empty;
        public void Dispose() => call?.Dispose();
        
        public Task<TResponse> Response => response.Task;
        public Task<Metadata> Headers => headers.Task;
        public MyStateObj(IMyCacheService cacheService,
            TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context, AsyncUnaryCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
        {
            _ = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var key = GetCacheKey(request, context);
                    var cacheValue = await cacheService.GetCacheAsync<TResponse>(key);
                    if (cacheValue is not null)
                    {
                        Status = Status.DefaultSuccess;
                        headers.TrySetResult(Metadata.Empty);
                        response.TrySetResult(cacheValue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        call = continuation(request, context);
                        headers.TrySetResult(await call.ResponseHeadersAsync);
                        var result = await call.ResponseAsync;
                        Status = call.GetStatus();
                        Trailers = call.GetTrailers();
                        response.TrySetResult(result);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex is RpcException rpc)
                    {
                        Status = rpc.Status;
                        Trailers = rpc.Trailers;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Status = new Status(StatusCode.Internal, ex.Message);
                    }
                    headers.TrySetException(ex);
                    response.TrySetException(ex);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

What it does is:

- create a custom state object that mimics the internal state of an async unary call
- begins an async task execution that *invokes* your cache, setting the local state if successful, otherwise deferring to the downstream continuation and using *that* to set the local state

as a side note: if possible, `context.Options.CancellationToken` should be used as a cancellation for `GetCacheAsync`.

If desirable, it would also be possible to *start* the `GetCacheAsync` call *before* the `Task.Run`, allowing you to test `.IsCompletedSuccessfully`, and *in that scenario* avoid the `Task.Run` altogether in the fully synchronous case.

That would look like:

```cs
            var key = GetCacheKey(request, context);
            var pending = cacheService.GetCacheAsync<TResponse>(key);
            if (pending.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
            {
                Status = Status.DefaultSuccess;
                headers.TrySetResult(Metadata.Empty);
                response.TrySetResult(pending.Result);
                return; // all completed synchronously
            }
            _ = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var cacheValue = await pending;
                    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you! i will research this. Also i posted below the another solution, using custom AsyncUnaryCallContinuation

Answer (score 1):

I aslo found the next solution, which seems to be worked. But i am not sure about posisbe issues with passing some arguments as null! into AsyncUnaryCallContinuation.

```
public override AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse> AsyncUnaryCall<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context,
            AsyncUnaryCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
        {
            var cachKey = GetCacheKey(request, context);

            AsyncUnaryCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> myContinuation =
                        (req, resp) =>
                        {
                            return new AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse>(
                                   MyCacheHandle(cachKey, request, context, continuation),
                                   null!,
                                   null!,
                                   null!,
                                   () => { });
                        };


            return base.AsyncUnaryCall(request, context, myContinuation);
        }

        private async Task<TResponse> MyCacheHandle<TRequest, TResponse>(string cachKey,
            TRequest request,
            ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context,
            AsyncUnaryCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
             where TRequest : class where TResponse : class
        {
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cachKey))
                {
                    var value = await _cacheService.GetCacheAsync<TResponse>(cachKey);
                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        return value;
                    }
                }

                var con = continuation(request, context);
                return await con.ResponseAsync;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Custom error", ex);
            }
        }
```